# Как не рисовать часть графика в plotly.express?

Tags: python, plotly

```
import plotly.express as px
```

Нарисовал графики статистик с помощью этой библиотеки.
Можно ли как то говорить библиотеке не рисовать графики по выбранным координатам.
Например этот график, начался не сначала года и хотелось бы убрать линию с нулями.
Как это сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или здесь. Линия 2022 года считается в реальном времени и хотелось бы, чтобы она не рисовалась там где время ещё не наступило
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот график рисуется так

```
fig_total_sum_month = px.line(df_merged_month, x='month_x', 
                        y=['sum_sum_2018', 'sum_sum_2019', 'sum_sum_2020', 
                           'sum_sum_2021', 'sum_sum_2022',], 
                        title='Обьем продаж накопительно помесячно', markers=True,)
fig_total_sum_month.update_traces(textposition="top center", textfont_size=9)


newnames = {'sum_2018': '2018', 'sum_2019': '2019',  'sum_2020': '2020', 'sum_2021': '2021', 
            'sum_2022': '2022', 
            'quantity_2018': '2018', 'quantity_2019': '2019', 'quantity_2020': '2020', 
            'quantity_2021': '2021', 'quantity_2022': '2022',
            'sum_sum_2018': '2018', 'sum_sum_2019': '2019', 'sum_sum_2020': '2020',
            'sum_sum_2021': '2021', 'sum_sum_2022': '2022',
            'quantity_sum_2018': '2018', 'quantity_sum_2019': '2019', 'quantity_sum_2020': '2020',
            'quantity_sum_2021': '2021', 'quantity_sum_2022': '2022',
           }
           
fig_total_sum_month.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(name = newnames[t.name], legendgroup = newnames[t.name],
                        hovertemplate = t.hovertemplate.replace(t.name, newnames[t.name])))
                        
fig_total_sum_month.show()
```

Данные берутся из датафрейма df_merged_month который получается сложным способом, приводить весь этот код не буду, смысла не вижу.
приведу часть данных из него, хотя и они нормально не помещаются сюда,но в целом представление дает, для ответа мне кажется хватает.
Так как хочетсяиспользовать функции библиотеки и не править датафрейм

```
week2 day   quantity_2018   quantity_2019   quantity_2020   quantity_2021   quantity_2022   sum_2018    sum_2019    sum_2020    sum_2021    ... sum_sum_2020    sum_sum_2021    sum_sum_2022    quantity_sum_2018   quantity_sum_2019   quantity_sum_2020   quantity_sum_2021   quantity_sum_2022   month   month_x                                                                                 
0   27  0   963 790 1075    1509    0   2739363 2731565 2387955 ... 2731565 2387955 3276469 0   963 790 1075    1509    0   
1   55  0   939 813 1241    1430    0   3012030 2820714 2892554 ... 5552279 5280509 6778775 0   1902    1603    2316    2939    1   Январь
2   83  0   984 893 1189    1595    0   3185895 3095158 2954839 ... 8647437 8235348 11157600    0   2886    2496    3505    4534    2   Февраль
3   111 0   1426    1087    1414    1567    0   4313913 3263951 3378994 ... 11911388    11614342    15355042    0   4312    3583    4919    6101    3   Март
4   139 0   1697    1608    2410    1773    0   4951087 4148278 5450504 ... 16059666    17064846    19958742    0   6009    5191    7329    7874    4   Апрель
5   167 0   1581    1771    2618    2136    0   5411199 5019597 6064795 ... 21079263    23129641    26343879    0   7590    6962    9947    10010   5   Май
6   195 419 1360    1339    1817    1320    1645984 4288190 3939914 4476494 ... 25019177    27606135    30773680    419 8950    8301    11764   11330   6   Июнь
```

Comment: В первом случае наверное проще из самих данных нули убрать. А вообще покажите код, которым вы рисуете. И данные хорошо бы приложить к вопросу по правилам.

Comment: Если нули убрать ошибка выходит, код сейчас приведу

Answer (score 1):

1 случай - сделайте замену нулей на np.nan,
2 случай - только если динамически удалять лишние данные. берете из системы текущую дату и там где 2022 год, удаляете ненужные строки